# Python how to use BeautifulSoap?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Given the following html response:

```
<div><input type="hidden" id="CSRFToken" name="CSRFToken" value="HFT/qajA/9FV2kJvMvONwurnFDY6GXZBAA=="/>Login<input type="password" id="LogBox" name="B8d5" /><input type="hidden" name="loginurl" value="/general/status.html"/><input id="login" type="submit" value="&nbsp;" /></div>
```

How can I retrieve the **value** of all:

1. Hidden fields only
2. whose name is `CSRFToken` or `CSRFToken2`

I tried:

```
return soup.find("input", {"name":"CSRFToken", }, type='hidden').get('value','')
```

Comment: My main problem now is to provide options for name so it can mach multiple

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your goal and just selecting these two put them into `['CSRFToken','CSRFToken2']`:

```
soup.find_all('input', {'name': ['CSRFToken','CSRFToken2'], 'type': 'hidden'})
```

This will give you a resultset of tags you have to iterate over to get its values.

---

As alternativ and more generic approach you can use `css selectors` in combination with `dict comprehension` as one of many options:

**Select all hidden inputs**

```
soup.select('input[type="hidden"]')
```

alternativ with `find_all()`

```
soup.find_all("input", type="hidden")
```

**Iterate over resultset**

```
{i.get('name'):i.get('value') for i in soup.select('input[type="hidden"]')}
```

**Iterate over resultset incl. check if name contains `CSRFToken`**

```
{i.get('name'):i.get('value') for i in soup.select('input[type="hidden"]') if 'CSRFToken' in i.get('name')}
```

This will give you a dict of name / value pairs based on your conditions.

#### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html='''
<div>
<input type="hidden" id="CSRFToken" name="CSRFToken" value="HFT/qajA/9FV2kJvMvONwurnFDY6GXZBAA=="/>
<input type="hidden" id="CSRFToken2" name="CSRFToken2" value="CSRFTOKEN2VALUE"/>
Login
<input type="password" id="LogBox" name="B8d5" />
<input type="hidden" name="loginurl" value="/general/status.html"/>
<input id="login" type="submit" value="&nbsp;" />
</div>
'''
soup=BeautifulSoup(html)


{i.get('name'):i.get('value') for i in soup.select('input[type="hidden"]') if 'CSRFToken' in i.get('name')}
```

#### Output

```
{'CSRFToken': 'HFT/qajA/9FV2kJvMvONwurnFDY6GXZBAA==', 'CSRFToken2': 'CSRFTOKEN2VALUE'}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've simulated your initial situation as best I can. You might still need to define an appropriate parser. Since you use return I assume that you want to write a function.

Just put the code given here into a function.

**Example Code**

```
#!pip install beautifulsoup4

#Added a simulated input with name CSRFToken2
simulated_html_input = """<div>
    <input type="hidden" id="CSRFToken" name="CSRFToken" value="HFT/qajA/9FV2kJvMvONwurnFDY6GXZBAA=="/>Login<input type="password" id="LogBox" name="B8d5" />
    <input type="hidden" name="loginurl" value="/general/status.html"/><input id="login" type="submit" value="&nbsp;" />
    <input type="hidden" id="CSRFToken" name="CSRFToken2" value="HFT/qajA/9FV2kJvMvONwurnFDY6GXZBAA==CSRFTOKEN2"/>Login<input type="password" id="LogBox" name="B8d5" />
</div>"""
#Init soup
#Embed code into function if needed
soup = bs(simulated_html_input)
try:
    token_list = soup.find_all('input', {'name': ['CSRFToken','CSRFToken2'], 'type': 'hidden'})
except Exception as e:
    print("Got unhandled exception %s" % str(e))
res = dict()
for i, ele in enumerate(token_list):
    #Modify output as needed 
    res["token_"+str(i)] = ele.get('value')
#In function use return 
print(res)
```

**Output is:**

> 'token_0': 'HFT/qajA/9FV2kJvMvONwurnFDY6GXZBAA==,
> 'token_1': 'HFT/qajA/9FV2kJvMvONwurnFDY6GXZBAA==CSRFTOKEN2'

Modify this code to meet your personal requirements